# weak*-convergence and weak operator topology - multiplication operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

The setting : let $(\Omega,\mu)$ $\sigma$-finite measure space and let $M_\phi : L^2(\Omega,\mu) \to L^2(\Omega,\mu)$ the multiplication operator with $\phi \in L^{\infty}(\Omega,\mu)$

I want to show  :

If $M_{\phi_{i}} \to M_\phi $ in weak operator topology, then $\phi_i \to \phi$ in weak*-topology

I already managed to show the reverse statement.

I don't know if this helps or even is true : Maybe I can write every $f \in L^1$ as product of two functions in $L^2$ ?

Comment: Which weak$^*$ topology do you mean? The one which comes from $L^1$?

Comment: The one coming from $L¹$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As alluded to in your question, the hardest part is writing an $L^1$ function as a product of two $L^2$ functions.  But this turns out to be easier than expected.

Suppose $M_{\phi_i}$ is WOT-convergent to $M_\phi$, and let $f\in L^1$ be given.  Then we can write $f=|f|e^{i\theta}$, where $\theta$ is a measurable function.  Now define 
\begin{align*}
g&=|f|^{1/2}e^{i\theta}, \\
h&=|f|^{1/2}.
\end{align*}
Then $g,h\in L^2$ and we have
$$\langle M_{\phi_i}g,h\rangle=\int\phi_i|f|e^{i\theta}\ d\mu
=\int\phi_if\ d\mu. $$
By hypothesis, $\langle M_{\phi_i}g,h\rangle\to\langle M_\phi g,h\rangle$, and thus
$$ \int\phi_if\ d\mu\to\int\phi f\ d\mu. $$
Since $f\in L^1$ was arbitrary, we know $\{\phi_i\}$ is weak$^*$-convergent to $\phi$.